# PHP: Dropbox Token Expired or Does not exist

Tags: php, dropbox-api

I am trying to copy a file from localhost to Dropbox account , i'm using curl to generate the token once i get the token i'm using it to upload the file but i'm getting error saying either Token Expired or Does not exist.

Here is my code:

## step1.php ##

```
  <?php
    session_start();

    require_once('config.php');

    $step_2_url = rawurlencode("http://nuftp.com/sanjeev/step-2.php");

   $ch = curl_init(); 

     $headers = array( 'Authorization: OAuth oauth_version="1.0",                     
  oauth_signature_method="PLAINTEXT", oauth_consumer_key="' . $app_key . '",  
  oauth_signature="' . $app_secret . '&"' );

  curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers ); 
   curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL,  
  "https://api.dropbox.com/1/oauth/request_token" );  
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE );  
     $request_token_response = curl_exec( $ch );
   error_log(var_export($request_token_response,true));


   parse_str( $request_token_response, $parsed_request_token );

   $json_access = json_decode( $request_token_response );

  if ( isset( $json_access->error ) ) {
    echo '<br><br>FATAL ERROR: ' . $json_access->error . '<br><br>';
    die();
    }

   $_SESSION['myapp'] = array();
   $_SESSION['myapp']['oauth_request_token'] =       
    $parsed_request_token['oauth_token'];
   $_SESSION['myapp']['oauth_request_token_secret'] = 
  $parsed_request_token['oauth_token_secret'];

  header( 'Location: https://www.dropbox.com/1/oauth/authorize?oauth_token=' 
. $parsed_request_token['oauth_token'] . '&oauth_callback=' . $step_2_url );
```

## step2.php ##

```
       <?php

       session_start();

      require_once('config.php');

     include 'dropbox-sdk-php-1.1.4/lib/Dropbox/autoload.php';

   use \Dropbox as dbx;


  $step_3_url = "step-3.php";
     if ( isset( $_GET['oauth_token'] ) && isset( $_GET['uid'] ) && isset(   
     $_SESSION['myapp'] ) ) {

  $ch = curl_init(); 

  $headers = array( 'Authorization: OAuth oauth_version="1.0",  

    oauth_signature_method="PLAINTEXT", oauth_consumer_key="' . $app_key .  
   '", oauth_token="'  .$_GET['oauth_token'] . '", oauth_signature="' .   
  $app_secret . '&' . $_SESSION['myapp']['oauth_request_token_secret'] . '"'  
  );
   curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers ); 

  curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, 
  "https://api.dropbox.com/1/oauth/access_token" );  
   curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE );  
    $access_token_response = curl_exec( $ch );

    error_log(var_export($request_token_response,true));

     parse_str( $access_token_response, $parsed_access_token );

    error_log( $access_token_response );

     $json_access = json_decode( $access_token_response );



   if ( isset( $json_access->error ) ) {
    echo '<br><br>FATAL ERROR: ' . $json_access->error . '<br><br>';
    die();
   }

   $_SESSION['myapp']['uid'] = $parsed_access_token['uid'];
   $_SESSION['myapp']['oauth_access_token'] =      
    $parsed_access_token['oauth_token'];
    $_SESSION['myapp']['oauth_access_token_secret'] = 
    $parsed_access_token['oauth_token_secret'];



   $dbxClient = new dbx\Client($_GET['oauth_token'], "PHP-Example/1.0");
   $accountInfo = $dbxClient->getAccountInfo();
     print_r($accountInfo);

      $f = fopen("working-draft.txt", "rb");
     $result = $dbxClient->uploadFile("/working-draft.txt",  
   dbx\WriteMode::add(), $f);
   fclose($f);
   print_r($result);

   $folderMetadata = $dbxClient->getMetadataWithChildren("/");
    print_r($folderMetadata);


    $f = fopen("working-draft.txt", "w+b");
    $fileMetadata = $dbxClient->getFile("/working-draft.txt", $f);
    fclose($f);
     print_r($fileMetadata);


    }
```

Somebody please suggest me what to do and where am i going wrong.

Comment: It looks like you're getting an OAuth 1 token but then ignoring that token altogether: `$dbxClient = new dbx\Client($_GET['oauth_token'], "PHP-Example/1.0");` That code looks for an `oauth_token` query parameter, which won't exist. I'm not sure the current PHP SDK even supports OAuth 1 anymore... I'd suggest just using OAuth 2. It's much simpler anyway, and then there's no need to write all this code by hand, since the SDK has methods to help you get the OAuth 2 token in the first place.

Comment: so can u tell me how do i proceed using OAuth 2 from generating token to uploading the file on dropbox

Comment: I'd just follow the example here: https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-php/blob/master/examples/web-file-browser.php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed  to get another working code and it works absolutely fine. It performs upload and download of files on dropbox. you can get the  working code from the link below,  however in the code i'm manually changing the names of the files to upload instead of holding it in a variable or giving an option to choose the file from directory.
In case there is any query , comment here and also revert me back on sanjeevks101@gmail.com 
Also go through the instructions page first before actually testing the code.

http://www.filehosting.org/file/details/471563/AccessDropboxUsingPHP-master.rar